# Let $Y$ be a dense subspace of a space $(X, d)$. Prove that if every Cauchy sequence $(y_n)⊂Y$ is convergent on $X$, so $X$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $Y$ be a dense subspace of a space $(X, d)$. Prove that if every Cauchy sequence $(y_n)⊂Y$ is convergent on $X$, so $X$ is complete.

Hello,it is difficult for me to use the properties of the metric spaces, I would be very grateful if you could help me to do this proof, thanks.

Comment: When you say "test" do you mean a graded examination? Do you mean "homework"? Also, what are some ideas you've had? You'll find questions that look like you want us to do your work for you will not be well received.

Comment: An apology, I am using the google translator and it has played me wrong

Comment: @HallaSurvivor and downvoter: To be fair when I first read the question the OP claimed they had given some thought to the problem by saying that they knew this for $\Bbb{R}^n$ but were having issues to generalize it to arbitrary metric spaces. They then edited and deleted this part from the question.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. To prove that $X$ is complete we need to show that $(x_n)$ converges. Since $Y$ is dense in $X$ each element in the sequence $(x_n)$ can be approximated by an element in $Y$. Then we can find a sequence $(y_n)$ in $Y$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)<\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and
$$
d(y_m,y_n) \leq d(y_m,x_m)+d(x_m,x_n)+d(x_n,y_m) < \frac{1}{m}+d(x_m,x_n)+\frac{1}{n},
$$
it follows that $(y_n)$ is also Cauchy. Thus, by hypothesis there is an $x \in X$ such that $y_n \to x$ in $X$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ and choose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{n}< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $d(x, y_n)< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n \geq N$. Then,
$$
d(x,x_n) \leq d(x,y_n)+d(y_n,x_n) < \varepsilon
$$
for all $n \geq N$. This proves that $x_n \to x$ in $X$ and therefore $X$ is complete.